# Getting an attribute from a forLoop element using onclick function

Tags: javascript, arrays, getattribute

I wanted to get the value of a forLoop element by using getAttribute with an 'onclick' attribute as well. But what I'm getting is the end value already. How do you get the value per loop on the exact value element being clicked? Here is my code;

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
const scrOutput = document.createElement('p');
const numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];

// For Loop Condition
for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'showOutput()');
  btn.setAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  btn.innerText = numbers[i];
  document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML += btn.outerHTML;
  const x = btn.getAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  console.log(x);  
}

function showOutput(){
  const btnVal = btn.getAttribute('value');
  scrOutput.innerText = btnVal;
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = scrOutput.outerHTML;
  console.log(btnVal);
}
```

Comment: `const btnVal = btn.getAttribute('value');` that only gets the last value set which is 9

Comment: your `for` loop sets the same attribute on the same button 10 times.  what are you trying to accomplish?  did you maybe mean to create 10 separate buttons first?

Comment: Yes. I created the buttons first. Then having an eventListener per button that will display on the #screen.

Answer (score 4):

Ok I have changed your code to work as expected

```js
const btn = document.createElement('button');
const scrOutput = document.createElement('p');
const numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];

// For Loop Condition
for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  // by adding `this` as an argument you make sure to pass the clicked button to the code inside the listener
  btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'showOutput(this)');
  btn.setAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  btn.innerText = numbers[i];
  document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML += btn.outerHTML;
  const x = btn.getAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  console.log(x);  
}

function showOutput(element) {
  // here the element is given on each click
  const btnVal = element.value;
  scrOutput.innerText = btnVal;
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = scrOutput.outerHTML;
  console.log(btnVal);
}
```

```html
<div id="numbers"></div>
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Here is a clean code that does what you want

```js
const numbersElement = document.querySelector("#numbers"),
  screenElement = document.querySelector("#screen"),
  numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
// looping over numbers array and create a new button and add it to numbers element
numbers.forEach(function(number) {
  numbersElement.innerHTML += `<button value="${number}">${number}</button>`;
});
// using event delegation instead of looping over the buttons
numbersElement.onclick = function(e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    screenElement.innerHTML = e.target.value;
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="numbers"></div>
<div id="screen"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell `showOutput()` function about which button is clicked. So send the button reference to that function and use it as `btn`

```js
const btn = document.createElement('button');
const scrOutput = document.createElement('p');
const numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];

// For Loop Condition
for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'showOutput(this)');
  btn.setAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  btn.innerText = numbers[i];
  document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML += btn.outerHTML;
  const x = btn.getAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  //console.log(x);  
}

function showOutput(btn){
  const btnVal = btn.getAttribute('value');
  scrOutput.innerText = btnVal;
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = scrOutput.outerHTML;
  //console.log(btnVal);
}
```

```html
<div id="screen">

</div>
<div id="numbers">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an event into the showOutput() function so that you can get the value of the button being click by doing `e.target.value` The target event property returns the element that triggered the event.

```
const btn = document.createElement('button');
const scrOutput = document.createElement('p');
const numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];

// For Loop Condition
for (let i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
  btn.setAttribute('onclick', 'showOutput(event)');
  btn.setAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  btn.innerText = numbers[i];
  document.getElementById('numbers').innerHTML += btn.outerHTML;
  const x = btn.getAttribute('value', numbers[i]);
  console.log(x);  
}

function showOutput(e){
  const btnVal = btn.getAttribute('value');
  scrOutput.innerText = e.target.value;
  document.getElementById('screen').innerHTML = scrOutput.outerHTML;
  console.log(btnVal);
}
```